# Missing result field in GET requests of the Facebook GRAPH API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to access the number of likes, shares and comments a given URL has received on facebook.

As I understand [this piece of doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/url), the following URL should give me what I want.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4?id=http://stackoverflow.com&fields=og_object,share&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

It gives me the following :

```
{
"og_object": {
   "id": "10150180465825637",
   "description": "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers",
   "title": "Stack Overflow",
   "type": "website",
   "updated_time": "2015-08-02T04:03:47+0000",
   "url": "http://stackoverflow.com/"
},
"share": {
   "comment_count": 4,
   "share_count": 32567
},
"id": "http://stackoverflow.com"
}
```

which includes comment_count = 4 and share_count = 32567.

But, if I refer to the [previously linked piece of doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/url), the number of likes should appear in `"og_object"` : there should be an `engagement` line with two elements inside, `count` (the number of likes) and `social_sentence` (a social sentence such as "You and 31,608,561 others like this.")

Obviously, these `engagement` and `count` elements are not there. How can I have them appear ?

---

---

NB : in the first URL, I tried changing the `&fields=og_object,share` part for any of these :

```
&fields=og_object.engagement,share
&fields=og_object.engagement.count,share
&fields=og_object,engagement,share
&fields=og_object,engagement,share
&fields=engagement,share
&fields=engagement.count,share
&fields=engagement,count,share
&fields=count,share

(NB : I also tried by putting `share` first in the list)
```

but none of them worked, I always get an error such as this one (every try which include a `.`) :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Syntax error \"Expected \"(\" instead of \",\".\" at character 20: og_object.engagement,share",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

or this one (every try without a `.` :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (engagement) on node type (URL)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100
   }
}
```

Comment: How to specify second level fields are explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4

Comment: Oh. Thanks. Indeed, it works...However, `og_object{engagement{count}}` and `share_count` display the same number... which is equal to the `total_count` when using the good old `http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=http://stackoverflow.com/`... It seems there is no way to get the number of likes and the number of shares with the graph api...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks to @WizKid, the answer is

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4?id=http://stackoverflow.com&fields=og_object{engagement},share&access_token=
```

or

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4?id=http://stackoverflow.com&fields=og_object{engagement{count}},share&access_token=
```

However, `og_object{engagement{count}}` and `share_count` display the same number... which is equal to the `total_count` when using the good old (& deprecated)

```
http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls=h‌​ttp://stackoverflow.com/
```

It seems there is no way to get the number of likes and the number of shares with the graph api...