# Using FQL with Facebook SDK for PHP v5

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I'd like to make the following FQL query using the latest Facebook SDK for PHP, is there a way to do it ?

```
SELECT like_count, share_count, comment_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://stackoverflow.com"
```

I tried to find answers or tutorials using Google and SO, but they all seem to refer to SDK for PHP prior to v5.

How do I do that ?

And while I'm at it : what is the maximum number of queries I can do in a given time ?

Thanks

(NB : I know FQL is deprecated and will be down in about a year, but as far as I know, there is no way to achieve what I want with the Graph API.)

Comment: You can make FQL queries via a “normal” API request for `fql?q={your_query}`. You might have to URL-encode your actual query here; but in general, that should still work with the PHP SDK v5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to achieve this using Graph API, see [URL Lookup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#urllookup). Please read the doc.

Below code should work (not tested):

```
$node = $fb->get('/?id='urlencode($url).'&fields=og_object,share'])->getGraphNode();

$likeCount = $node['og_object']['engagement']['count'];
$shareCount = $node['share']['share_count'];
$commentCount = $node['share']['comment_count'];
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I've tested, `$likeCount` and `$shareCount` will display the same number, which is equal to the sum of likes, shares and comments... so it doesn't achieve what I need. (See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31776718/4348534).

Comment: Then you should [open a bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/), but [this one](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/718115468292419/) might be related.

Comment: Indeed, it does seem to be related. Merci !

Comment: You're welcome. Once the bug will be fixed, I think above solution will work like a charm with Graph API :)

Comment: Well, it seems I'm screwed... https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1626816337594065/